# Pass DataGridView cell BackColor to variable for later use in c#

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, datagridview

Project info: Windows Application in c#, .net 4.0

I'm working on a form with a DataGridView, this dgv has pre-established cell BackColors from an earlier function in the application.

I'm adding a new *private void* function that checks a quantity column in this DataGridView, this new function will highlight cells for the qty column where the qty values match a certain criteria.

In my loop, where I check the data in the DataGridView, I need to capture the existing BackColor so I can set it back to that existing color, if the qty value does not match my criteria.

I'm using a `foreach (DataGridViewRows r in myDGV.Rows)` loop to check the cells in my DataGridView, how can I capture the existing BackColor of my cells inside this loop?

Answer (score 0):

The row, r, has a Cells property and each cell has a Style property.  One part of the style is the BackColor.   Does that help?  If not, please explain more about what you're trying to do.

Comment: I've tried that, sorry should have explained before. I tried `row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor`, `row.Cells["Qty"].Style.BackColor` and `row.Cells["Qty"].Style.BackColor.ToString()` but the variables always say either *"Color [Empty]"* or *{Name=0, ARGB=(0,0,0,0)}*